# Python Memory Error while loading data into list

Tags: python, json, memory

I'm working with JSON Files, and trying to split consolidated JSON File to individual Files. But when the source file size is 503308 kb, my python code is giving error.I have tried with Pycharm and Cmd Prompt but its not working for me.
Following is the Error--
**line 67, in _buffer_decode
    codecs.utf_8_decode(input[3:], errors, final)
MemoryError**

I have been looking for solutions, but nothing worked for me.
Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance :)

```
import json
import glob

s_path = "D:\\User\\Desktop\\users\\SourceFolder\\"
extension = "*.json"
for file in glob.iglob(s_path+extension):
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8-sig") as json_data:


        d_list = json.load(json_data)
        item_count = len(d_list)
        target_path = 'D:\\Desktop\\users\\DumpingFolder\\'
        print(item_count)
        for item in d_list:
            file_name = "Raw_Response_" + str(item['id']) + ".json"
            print(file_name)
            with open(target_path+file_name, 'w+') as file_obj:
                json.dump(item, file_obj, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried just loading the JSON? Can it fit into your available memory?

Comment: Does the code work with small files? Please post a minimal exaple of input data. What other solutions have you tried that didn't work? Have you tried sed or awk or other text editing automation tools?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I have tried loading the JSON and it is fitting into available memory